# SyntaxError: invalid syntax on environ.has_key

Tags: python

I'm a little noob in python, and i need help please, i have this code

```
numparts = 0
if (os.environ.has_key('DECODED_PARTS'))
    numparts = int(os.environ['DECODED_PARTS'])
    print numparts
```

but everytime i try i get thr following error

```
File "sms_listener.py", line 12
    if  os.environ.has_key('DECODED_PARTS')
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i seach for environ syntax and oder codes and they are correct.
Can u help me find the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing ":" at the end of the if

```
if 'DECODED_PARTS' in os.environ:
    numparts = int(os.environ['DECODED_PARTS'])
    print numparts
```

Also you don't need to warp the expression with another "( )"

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `:`; it is mandatory in compound statements:

```
if os.environ.has_key('DECODED_PARTS'):
```

Comment: thank you soo much, how come I did not notice it, the thing is that all the examples I saw were not the: eg this [link](http://93.93.128.176/forums/viewtopic.php?t=73794&p=531624)